# AngularJS Dynamically adding and removing HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to create a website where depending on what button is pressed, it will load HTML in a container corresponding to that button without having to reload the page. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to where I can learn how to do this. Thanks

Comment: I think you basically need to learn angular, or maybe any front-end js framework. You might try [angular2](https://angular.io/) or [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) two most popular frameworks right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with the Angular UI Router.

This page has a demo that (I think) does what you want:

https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/helloworld

There may be some studying required to master this :)

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I was looking for Thanks!